# Issue locking the phone before the camera is fully initialized. When I unlock the phone it breaks

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, camera, windows-phone

I am developing a camera app and I am having a problem when I leave the app before the camera is fully initialized and I try to return to them.
In my **OnNavigatedFrom** method I have that:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
    try
            {
                if (cameraInit)
                {
                    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => { 
                        if (cam != null)
                        {
                            cam.Dispose();
                            cam.CaptureCompleted -= cam_CaptureCompleted;
                            cam.CaptureImageAvailable -= cam_CaptureImageAvailable;
                            cam.AutoFocusCompleted -= cam_AutoFocusCompleted;
                            CameraButtons.ShutterKeyPressed -= OnButtonFullPress;
                            cam = null;
                            cameraInit = false;
                        }
                    });
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
}
```

This is the **OnNavigatedTo** method I have:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
// Check to see if the camera is available on the device.
        if (PhotoCamera.IsCameraTypeSupported(CameraType.Primary) == true)
        {

            if (cam == null)
            {
                cam = new Microsoft.Devices.PhotoCamera(CameraType.Primary);
                //Create the camera event handlers
                //// Event is fired when the capture sequence is complete.
                cam.CaptureCompleted += new EventHandler<CameraOperationCompletedEventArgs>(cam_CaptureCompleted);
                //// Event is fired when the capture sequence is complete and an image is available.
                cam.CaptureImageAvailable += new EventHandler<Microsoft.Devices.ContentReadyEventArgs>(cam_CaptureImageAvailable);
                //// The event is fired when auto-focus is complete.
                cam.AutoFocusCompleted += new EventHandler<CameraOperationCompletedEventArgs>(cam_AutoFocusCompleted);
                //// The event is fired when the shutter button receives a full press.
                cam.Initialized += cam_Initialized;
                CameraButtons.ShutterKeyPressed += OnButtonFullPress;
            }
            ////Set the VideoBrush source to the camera.
            canvasCamBrush.SetSource(cam);
}
```

And this is my **cam_initialized** method:

```
void cam_Initialized(object sender, CameraOperationCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Succeeded)
        {
            cameraInit = true;
            if (cameraInit)
            {
                cam.FlashMode = FlashMode.Off;
            }
        }
    }
```

The main problem is that when the **onNavigatedFrom** method is launched the cam is not fully initialized and then it breaks on the **OnNavigatedTo** method when I return to the app so I need to wait there until the **cam_initialized** method is fired before run the **onNavigatedFrom**.

Here is an example of other person who had this problem but I couldn't make it work:

[PhotoCamera issue while Initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21021913/photocamera-issue-while-initialization)

Thanks everyone,
L

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it making an "infinite loop" before leave the app until the cam is fully initialized. The **OnNavigatedFrom** code is that:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
         try
            {
             while (!cameraInit)
                {
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
                }
                if (cameraInit)
                {
                    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => { 
                        if (cam != null)
                        {
                            cam.Dispose();
                            cam.CaptureCompleted -= cam_CaptureCompleted;
                            cam.CaptureImageAvailable -= cam_CaptureImageAvailable;
                            cam.AutoFocusCompleted -= cam_AutoFocusCompleted;
                            CameraButtons.ShutterKeyPressed -= OnButtonFullPress;
                            cam = null;
                            cameraInit = false;
                        }
                    });
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
}
```

That is the best solution that I could find. Hope that can help someone.
Thanks